# Escaping characters, SQL Injection

Tags: sql, escaping, sql-injection

I have this query in a SQL injection problem:

```
"SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE keywords LIKE \%" + querystring + "\% AND owner=’" + owner + "’;"
```

where querystring is directly input by the user and owner is automatically set.
The syntax is supposed to be correct but I don't understand what the \% is doing in this position ... the query is incorrect isn't it? It is supposed to lead to SQL injection problem exploiting the problem with the query but this "\%" is really perturbating me.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that querystring has

```
'; SELECT * FROM SYS.DATABASES; --
```

What do you thing it could happen if a hacker tries it with a CURL tool?
Your syntax will bring everything from the first query and then the list of all databases, in fact this is a very simple example. In some environments these kind of injection can allow a hacker to get to the whole server and even the domain, even if the firewall is well configured.

Comment: What I mean is there is no point in writing \% after LIKE, it's not correct so even if we write what you wrote, we get an erro because of this \% not correctly placed don't we?

Comment: You are right it will fail the SQL parsing. In order to pass parsing it needs to be single quote